# FormatMessage is not supported for this application type

Tags: windows-10-universal

When running app certification on my app, I'm getting this error from supported apis.

API FormatMessage in api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll is not supported for this application type. System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll calls this API.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?  I'm not using anything from that namespace directly.  If this is a 3rd party library calling something in System.Diagnostics.Tracing, is there a way to track down which one?  I'm not referencing System.Diagnostics.Tracing directly in my app.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am getting the same error when I run the Windows App Certification Kit for my application.

Comment: @nor0x  No, I sure haven't.  I suspect it might be a library that I'm using from Nuget.  Maybe we should compare 3rd party libraries?

Comment: I submitted my app via the dev-center and it passed certification without any problems. 
I use Template10, SQLite-Net-PCL and SQLite-Extensions

Comment: Interesting, I guess I'll try to submit it to the dev center then, my cert tool is the one that's been giving me those errors.  I also use the sqlite packages, but not Template10.

Comment: If you're running the cert kits against Debug builds you may hit issues like this. If it still happens when running against Release builds we'd love to track it down. Feel free to mail us at dotnetnative@microsoft.com.

Comment: @MattWhilden can you confirm the answer below? On one hand one can run `appcert.exe` on the "external" appxupload (the one generated outside the `appxupload`), but on the other hand one could then miss errors that only appear for the `appxbundle` inside the `appxupload` (we hit such errors regarding assemblies built in DEBUG mode).

Answer (score 2):

For my app, I will get exactly this error if I unzip the .appxupload and use the file .appxbundle inside it to run App Cert Kit against, even though the same .appxupload will publish on store without issue. However, if I run Cert Kit against the .appxbundle in folder _Test generated by the same build, there will be no error reported. So I guess the .appxupload is really not intended to be installed outside of store.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well after a string a successful submissions of the same app to the store. Through trial and error I found out that if I built the app in Release mode, and THEN created the packages for the store, everything worked. If the last build was in Debug mode, and then I flipped the configuration to "Release" (without building in Release) and then creating the package,  I would get this error. So that's something worth trying - Rebuild All in Release mode and then create the store packages.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem, i issued three packages to the store with the same error during certification, in my case, the solution was to set **false** the **EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile** tag in the csproj (i didnt found it on the project properties editor), although I replicated the failed test just as huyc replied, the app was successfully submited to the store.