# How to check Windows app rejection issue?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, app-certification-kit

I recently submitted an app on Windows Store and it was rejected as one Supported APIs test failed. Can someone please suggest how can I find the root cause of the issue? I have attached exact message from Microsoft certification process

[image]

Comment: [This](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/formatmessage-in-api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0-dll-is-not-supported-for-this-application-type.453161/), [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/36102429-dcf5-42c5-9528-8ff77f766fe1/uwpunsupported-windows-81-api-in-uwp-10?forum=wpdevelop), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091884/formatmessage-is-not-supported-for-this-application-type) may give some pointers

Comment: can you find that dll and remove it including all references?

Comment: You might try building your app in release mode and then generate your package for Store submission to see if it works. Actually, you can still upload your package to the Store if it only failed this test. Sometimes, it won't receive the same error in online Wack test.

Comment: @MattewWu-MSFT I tried to upload two times but it rejected again. Also, I have uploaded two packages one for Windows Phone 8/8.1 and other for Windows 10. So, can you suggest if I can find which version has this issue?